# MySQL C# Query trouble - Updating table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'am having trouble with this function I'm creating to Update my database. The Update faculty member seems to work perfectly while the Updating of the person tables does not . I'm presuming that the MySQL Query isn't correct for updating the person table.

Additional INFO: My code is hooked to an GUI mock as of right now for testing purposes . the Update string with @Id.. its just to select which ID I wish to change..

```
public static void Update(string update,string fName, string lName, string DOB, string postCode, string address, string phoneNumber,
                                        bool isTenured, string qualifications, string previousEmployment)
            {
                MySqlConnection conn;
                MySqlCommand cmd;
                string sql = "UPDATE person SET firstName = @FirstName , lastName = @LastName, DOB = @DOB, phoneNumber = @PhoneNumber, address = @Address, postCode = @PostCode WHERE ID =@Id;";
                GetConnection(out conn, out cmd, sql);

                try
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", update);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", fName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", postCode);

                    long id = (long)cmd.LastInsertedId;

                    sql = "UPDATE facultymember SET isTenured = @IsTenured, qualifications = @Qualifications, previousEmployment = @PreviousEmployment WHERE Person_personID=@Id";
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsTenured", isTenured);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qualifications", qualifications);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PreviousEmployment", previousEmployment);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

                catch (NullReferenceException nre)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(nre.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Updated");
                        cmd.Connection.Close();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you please share what error you get or that unexpected behavior of that function.

Comment: "The Update faculty member seems to work perfectly" how could you say that, while your query have @ID parameter but in you didn't add that parameter in command object.

Comment: @Allonaz Are you sure your second query works? Because I don't think so `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add `@Id` parameter in your second sql query.

```
sql = "UPDATE facultymember
       SET isTenured = @IsTenured, qualifications = @Qualifications, previousEmployment = @PreviousEmployment
       WHERE Person_personID=@Id";
                        //   ^^^^
cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsTenured", isTenured);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qualifications", qualifications);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PreviousEmployment", previousEmployment);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", YourIdValue);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` like;

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
  //
}
```